# Can I make an alias with a parameter?

Tags: linux, unix

So i want to run a script that requires me to input the name of a file.

For example:
`/userthatisnotme/bin/move filename`

So I want to make it easier for me to remember, so I can just type `move filename` instead of that whole path.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your bash_profile (or other shell profile script):

```
alias my_move="/userthatisnotme/bin/move"
```

Examples of aliases for ls here: http://github.com/adamv/dotfiles/blob/master/bashrc#L45

The "parameters" get placed after the alias name. For more complicated situations, you could make a shell function instead of an alias.

Answer (score 1):

use a sub routine.

```
mymove(){
 /userthatisnotme/bin/move "$1"
}
```

save this in your library eg `mylibrary`. when you want to use it, just source it. `. mylibrary` or source `mylibrary`